# Pulling HTML string from db make changes and update with HTML string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, strip-tags

I'm working on a universal type notification page. Notify of a customer change or even a change for a time off request. Kinda of at a roadblock thought wise.

Currently I have when a user submits a page for form a or b. It sends a notification to a pending page. From there a mgr/sup can update, approve, deny. I currently have a controller that handles the user sending the request and creates a HTML string for their request so it it looks pretty and highlights what a user changed from the original customer information. I then use the string to put in a JQuery dialog for the mgr/sup to actually view the HTML form of what the user is requesting.

I know there is a PHP function that pulls all the HTML out of the string, but trying to figure out a good way to then allow the mgr/sup to then make a change to the string and update the string an update the the db.

Looking for ideas more than anything. Thanks!

this is another example of what I have pushing towards the db. Initially they search for an item that is currently in the data base and fills in inputs with the changeable properties of the item. If for example a change of size is requested the put the new size and submit and I build a $notification_str

```
 $notification_str = "'<table align=center width=\"100%\"><tr class=\'th1\'><td colspan=3 align=center>Item Change</td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>".$size_red."Item Size:</td>
                                            <td><input type=\"text\" name=item_size value=\"".$_REQUEST['item_size']."\"</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>".$description_red."Item Description:</td>
                                            <td><input size=\"45\" type=\"text\" name=item_description value=\"".$_REQUEST['item_description']."\"</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>".$weight_red."Item Weight:</td>
                                            <td><input type=\"text\" name=item_weight value=\"".$_REQUEST['item_weight']."\"</td>
                                        <tr>
                                    </table'"
```

This is inserted into a pending_changes column of a db table where the manager can open it in another page in a pretty little dialog modal. I would like them to them be able to make changes in the modal and update the actual HTML if needed. I also could be overthinking this too.

Comment: I read your question three times. And I'm not sure what do you want exactly. Can you give us some more informations what you're planing to do, or an better example, so we've chance to understand you?

Comment: So in general what you looking for is a small notification system. A User can request changes by a form for an Item.
An Administrator can take a look in your "outstanding changes" list and have two choices accept the changes or ignore it.

Did I understand you correct? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yea for the most part. I have an update, approve, and deny option in the modal that will use the same modal for item change, customer, change, etc. Eventually this will be automated to a progress db (for an ERP system). Looking into options as far as if the City was spelled wrong for a customer change request, the admin could correct it, update it, Think the overall option needed is to take html break it a apart and "variablize" the needed fields.

Comment: You want to let users send these HTML forms and make administrators to be able to observe and approve these changes. So what is your problem now?